# How to create a simple AEM form

Tags: osgi, aem

I am trying to create a simple AEM form that will have multiple sections with different fields. For example:

```
Section 1: Personal Information
First Name _______
Last Name _______

Section 2: Address
Address 1 _____
Address 2 _____
```

I have never created an AEM form before but I have created a workflow step. How different is creating a form? This is how my project looks (the one I use for workflow in intelliJ)

[image]

When I run local instance of AEM, these are the options I see on the left.

[image]

I am on CQ5 5.5

**Questions**

1. Should I be creating the form in IntelliJ or directly in AEM? I want the form to save data etc.
2. If I create it in intelliJ, do I deploy a jar file to AEM?
3. Can someone please point me to a tutorial that walks through creating a simple form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here is hello world tutorial for InteliJ IDEA 12 [idea tutorial](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2013/08/developing-aem-561-day-cq-applications.html);
2. Also may be useful to install [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7328?pr=idea), instead of using FileVault;
3. You need to create component(your form) [example](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/components.html) . [Adabe doc about components](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/components.html);
4. Also you may be need to create bundle-service, to procces input info [example](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/first-osgi.html);
5. [How to debug aem in idea](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/ht-intellij.html).